# Background Image doesn't display bottom right

Tags: css, background-image

Has something changed in CSS that I don't know about? I am trying to put an image on the bottom right of the screen. I don't know why it is doing this but it seems to be pushing the image off the screen where I can't see it. if I remove `bottom` it puts the image on the right but not on the bottom. If I do `right top` the image shows in the top right. So why isn't it showing on the `right bottom`?

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: BentonSans, 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
}
body{
    font-size: 12pt;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("/media/images/image1.jpg");
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suspicion is that it is related to container sizes.

Do you have this somehwere in your CSS?

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: yup! I just found that solution too!

Comment: I think `min-height` and `min-width` would be better though.